# Combine multiple list elements and generate another list in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, zip

I have 3 lists and I want to make a new list combining element by element into another list in python. This is an example.

```
ID = [1, 2, 3, 4]
Name = [Sam, Tom, Jett, Cal]
Age = [29, 28, 30, 19]
```

The output should look like this.

```
[{ID: 1, Name: Sam, Age: 29}, {ID: 2, Name: Tom, Age: 28},{ID: 3, Name: Jett, Age: 30},{ID: 4, Name: Cal, Age: 19}]
```

How can I do this in python?

Answer (score 1):

`zip` all the lists together and use a list comprehension:

```py
ID = [1, 2, 3, 4]
Name = ['Sam', 'Tom', 'Jett', 'Cal']
Age = [29, 28, 30, 19]
res = [{'ID': i, 'Name': name, 'Age': age} for i, name, age in zip(ID, Name, Age)]
```

An alternative with the key names defined in a separate list:

```py
keys = ['ID', 'Name', 'Age']
res = [dict(zip(keys, vals)) for vals in zip(ID, Name, Age)]
```